# Deserializing XML with list using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I have the following XML that I'd like to deserialize to Java POJO.

```
<testdata>
    <foo>
        <bar>
            <![CDATA[MESSAGE1]]>
        </bar>
        <bar>
            <![CDATA[MESSAGE2]]>
        </bar>
        <bar>
            <![CDATA[MESSAGE3]]>
        </bar>
    </foo>
</testdata>
```

I have the following Java classes

```
public class TestData {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "foo")
    private Foo foo;

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

}
```

I have another class like below

```
public class Foo {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "bar")
    @JacksonXmlCData
    private List<String> barList;

    public List<String> getBarList() {
        return barList;
    }

    public void setBarList(List<String> barList) {
        this.barList = barList;
    }
}
```

Now when I run the code using the class below I get an exception

```
private void readXml() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File("/Users/temp.xml");
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    String xml = GeneralUtils.inputStreamToString(new FileInputStream(file));
    TestData testData = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, TestData.class);
    System.out.println(testData.getFoo()
                               .getBarList());
}
```

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token

How do I convert `bar` elements into a `List`? I tried multiple things but I keep getting some or the other errors

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to indicate that `<bar>` is a wrapping element for your collection of `String` messages:

This should work in your `Foo` class:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "bar")
@JacksonXmlCData
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private List<String> barList;
```

Comment: What if "bar" had an an attribute, ie <bar name="whatever">, and I wanted to capture that?

Comment: With Jackson you can look at @.JacksonXmlProperty with isAttribute=true as property of the annotation.

Comment: this saved my life!

Comment: I have the same problem but for me issue is that this only returns the first element of the bar and others are not there.

Comment: @hovanessyan

 should i add @.JacksonXmlProperty with isAttribute=true  this on Bar pojo where the name field ? or 

at the Foo Pojo , in the Bar field ? like below :
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "bar",isAttribute = true)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have in your input xml a list of bar elements with an attribute like

```
<testdata>
    <foo>
        <bar name="John">
            <![CDATA[MESSAGE1]]>
        </bar>
        <bar name="Mary">
            <![CDATA[MESSAGE2]]>
        </bar>
        <bar name="Bill">
            <![CDATA[MESSAGE3]]>
        </bar>
    </foo>
<testdata>
```

you could create a `Bar` class and include a list of it as a field of the `Foo` class:

```
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "bar")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Bar> barList;
```

The `Bar` class would be:

```
    class Bar {    
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String name; 

        @JacksonXmlCData
        private String content;
   }
```

Remember to include getters and setters for the `Bar` class.